# Change part of a timestamp (not relatively) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I saw similar questions here, e. g. "I want to change time from 13:00 to 17:00" and always answers were "use `'13:00' + INTERVAL '4 hours'`"

BUT, what I need is to SET the `date_part` value to existing date, without knowing the exact interval size, something opposite to `date_part` (`extract`) function.

For example:

```sql
-- NOT A REAL FUNCTION
SELECT date_set('hour', date, 15)
FROM (VALUES ('2021-10-23 13:14:43'::timestamp), ('2020-11-02 10:00:34')) as dates (date)
```

Which result will be:

```
2021-10-23 15:14:43
2020-11-02 15:00:34
```

As you can see, this cannot be done with simple `+/- INTERVAL` expression.

### Possible solution

What I've already found on SO is:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', date) + INTERVAL '15 hour'
FROM (VALUES ('2021-10-23 13:14:43'), ('2020-11-02 10:00:34')) as dates (date)
```

But this variant does not preserve minutes and seconds.

Although, I can fix this issue, simply adding back minutes, seconds and microseconds of original timestamp:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', date) + INTERVAL '15 hour'
  + (extract(minute from date) || ' minutes')::interval
  + (extract(microsecond from date) || ' microseconds')::interval
FROM (VALUES ('2021-10-23 13:14:43.001240'::timestamp), ('2020-11-02 10:00:34.000001')) as dates (date)
```

This will output:

```
2021-10-23 15:14:43.001240
2020-11-02 15:00:34.000001
```

And it solves the problem.

But honestly, I'm not very pleased by this solution. Maybe someone knows better variants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind the below function is to clear the unit (subtract the corresponding interval) and add a given interval.

```sql
create or replace function timestamp_set(unit text, tstamp timestamp, num int)
returns timestamp language sql immutable as $$
    select tstamp+ (num- date_part(unit, tstamp))* format('1 %s', unit)::interval
$$;
```

Check:

```sql
select
    date,
    timestamp_set('hour', date, 15) as hour_15,
    timestamp_set('min', date, 33) as min_33,
    timestamp_set('year', date, 2022) as year_2022
from (
    values 
        ('2021-10-23 13:14:43'::timestamp), 
        ('2020-11-02 10:00:34')
    ) as dates (date)

        date         |       hour_15       |       min_33        |      year_2022
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 2021-10-23 13:14:43 | 2021-10-23 15:14:43 | 2021-10-23 13:33:43 | 2022-10-23 13:14:43
 2020-11-02 10:00:34 | 2020-11-02 15:00:34 | 2020-11-02 10:33:34 | 2022-11-02 10:00:34
(2 rows)
```

Try it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6ea6dc44fbf7f25315e301876de82453)

Comment: A true gem (with a few redundant single quotes :)).

Comment: Yes, `format()` gives a text, extra quotes are redundant. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Well, they are very small and squeeze easily through tight cables, so no big deal :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no function to set a specific part of a timestamp, but you can use date/time arithmetic to produce the result you want. For example:

```
select d + (15 - extract(hour from d)) * interval '1 hour' from dates
```

Result:

```
?column?
------------------------
2021-10-23T15:14:43.000Z
2020-11-02T15:00:34.000Z
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/93zN3dHGGe6o8M7WeG5sSd/0).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD 15:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as fixed_time
FROM (VALUES ('2021-10-23 13:14:43'::timestamp), ('2020-11-02 10:00:34'::timestamp)) as dates (ts);


2021-10-23 15:14:43.000000 +00:00
2020-11-02 15:00:34.000000 +00:00
```

Comment: That's kind of cheating, but heck it works. +1 I learned something new about PostgreSQL today.